# iframe not displaying on iphone + wordpress platform

Tags: ios, wordpress, iframe

we have 2 iframes that server 3rd party content on 2 separate pages.
The behavior is odd. If you go to one page the iframe loads and then if you go to the other page it does not. If you clear your cache and do the opposite still only 1 iframe shows. This is on iphone only and we are running iOS 9.1.
We do not allow cache on those pages and have added the css below just in case it was an issue there.

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: scroll;
```

The 2 pages are http://crossfitdovevalley.com/schedule/ and http://crossfitdovevalley.com/wod/ and are on the WordPress platform.
I see no errors in firebug besides `Error: Permission denied to access property "document"` but that's on desktop and will not affect mobile I 
dont think. I come here as a last resort for help to see if someone
has also experienced iframe issues on iPhones using Wordpress.

Comment: Could you try to add a random GET parameter (like timestamp) on iframes urls to prevent them to be cached?

Comment: We are using the html meta pragma and expires to make sure pages dont get cached.

Comment: The meta pragma is sometimes get ignored. What could you loose trying?